# how can we install Magento2.4 on AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: magento2.3, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

How we can install Magento 2.4 on EC2 Amazon Instance. I am a newbie and new to coding, it will be a great help if someone can tell me the exact steps and commands I have to run in order to install Magento.

Comment: Did you install any os or lamp on your aws instance?

Comment: i installed ubuntu Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type

Comment: First install lamp and need applications on your server. Than install Magento.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.4 you need to install PHP 7.4 and elasticsearch. You can use this to install magento 2.4.x in your local.

Source: https://magentip.com/install-magento-2-4-x-on-ubuntu-with-elasticsearch/

This will help you to install magento on aws.